# How to handle REST Nouns when data can come from two sources?

Tags: api, rest

We have product images which are stored on the filesystem under a manufacturer folder and those files are assigned to products in an IMAGE table.

Our developer needs two sets of data from the REST API:

1. Get all images for a product (comes from IMAGE table)

   ```
   /api/manufacturer/[:id]/product[:id]/product-image
   ```
2. Get all product images under a manufacturer (comes from file system)

   ```
   /api/manufacturer/[:id]/product-image
   ```

We can't take from the table in the second example because the client wants to keep unused images around for when products come in (products often use the same image as similar products).

Our developer pointed out that this setup is confusing for API users because the data comes from two different sources (IMAGE table vs. File System)

How is this properly done? Two different nouns?

Answer (score 0):

The users of the API should not care about the back-end architecture.  It does not matter that the API's look similar (same noun) but the data is coming from different sources.  Let the middle layer (or data layer) worry about that and deal with it elegantly.  The reason we modulize and layer our architecture is so that things like this can be done without one layer (or module) worrying about it.